# "until the end of (the) time(s)"?

Tags: grammar, phrases, idioms

I'm trying to translate a phrase from Spanish ("Hasta el final de los tiempos") and I was thinking of using one of these phrases:

1. Until the end of time
2. Until the end of the times
3. Until the end of times

I googled all these three and all show up in examples so I'm wondering. Should time be singular or plural? Should I use "the"? Personally I like 3) but I'm not sure if this would be valid or the most appropriate.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U! I edited your post slightly to make your question a little more clear. If you don't like the edit you can roll it back.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be *until the end of time*. The *time* here is referring to the entirety of time itself, from the Creation until the end of the world, perhaps. *Time* here is not countable, so you cannot use *times*.

Comment: Time _in this sense_ is not countable. In other senses, of course, it is.